# React testing library on change for Material UI Select component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am trying to test the `onChange` event of a [Select component](https://material-ui.com/api/select/) using [react-testing-library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library).

I grab the element using `getByTestId` which works great, then set the value of the element and then call `fireEvent.change(select);` but the `onChange` is never called and the state is never updated.

I have tried using both the select component itself and also by grabbing a reference to the underlying `input` element but neither works.

Any solutions? Or is this a know issue?

Comment: 1. Most of the answers didn't work for me. 
2. Many examples did not provide enough context to make anything of them.

[Here the solution, that worked for me][1]. (based on [this][2] answer)


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74388456/6702598
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68216785/6702598

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This turns out to be super complicated when you are using Material-UI's `Select` with `native={false}` (which is the default). This is because the rendered input doesn't even have a `<select>` HTML element, but is instead a mix of divs, a hidden input, and some svgs. Then, when you click on the select, a presentation layer (kind of like a modal) is displayed with all of your options (which are not `<option>` HTML elements, by the way), and I believe it's the clicking of one of these options that triggers whatever you passed as the `onChange` callback to your original Material-UI `<Select>`

All that to say, if you are willing to use `<Select native={true}>`, then you'll have actual `<select>` and `<option>` HTML elements to work with, and you can fire a change event on the `<select>` as you would have expected.

Here is test code from a Code Sandbox which works:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, cleanup, fireEvent } from "react-testing-library";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetAllMocks();
});

afterEach(() => {
  cleanup();
});

it("calls onChange if change event fired", () => {
  const mockCallback = jest.fn();
  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <div>
      <Select
        native={true}
        onChange={mockCallback}
        data-testid="my-wrapper"
        defaultValue="1"
      >
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
  const wrapperNode = getByTestId("my-wrapper")
  console.log(wrapperNode)
  // Dig deep to find the actual <select>
  const selectNode = wrapperNode.childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
  fireEvent.change(selectNode, { target: { value: "3" } });
  expect(mockCallback.mock.calls).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

You'll notice that you have to dig down through the nodes to find where the actual `<select>` is once Material-UI renders out its `<Select>`.  But once you find it, you can do a `fireEvent.change` on it.

The CodeSandbox can be found here:

[image: Edit firing change event for material-ui select]

Comment: Thanks @Alvin Lee this is what we needed. For future reference we set the test id in the `inputProps` so: `inputProps={{ "data-testid": "my-wrapper" }}` and then didn't have to get the select node by referencing 2 child nodes.

Comment: @RobSanders Glad it worked out for you! That's a helpful tip about setting the test id rather than digging down through the child nodes. Happy coding!

Answer (score 167):

material-ui's select component uses the mouseDown event to trigger the popover menu to appear. If you use `fireEvent.mouseDown` that should trigger the popover and then you can click your selection within the listbox that appears. see example below.

```
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent, within } from "react-testing-library";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

it('selects the correct option', () => {
  const {getByRole} = render(
     <>  
       <Select fullWidth value={selectedTab} onChange={onTabChange}>
         <MenuItem value="privacy">Privacy</MenuItem>
         <MenuItem value="my-account">My Account</MenuItem>
       </Select>
       <Typography variant="h1">{/* value set in state */}</Typography>
     </>
  );
  
  fireEvent.mouseDown(getByRole('button'));

  const listbox = within(getByRole('listbox'));

  fireEvent.click(listbox.getByText(/my account/i));

  expect(getByRole('heading')).toHaveTextContent(/my account/i);
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to test it. You can get more details by checking how material-ui test their component https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Select/Select.test.js

Comment: If I have multiple <Select> how can i achieve the same ?

Comment: @YaserAliPeedikakkal If your `Select` has a label, you can target the `Select` by using `getByLabelText()` for the first click.  The element with `role="listbox"` appears after the click, so unless you've added an element yourself that has `role="listbox"`, the next query will only find the 1 popup from your targeted click. For example, with `user-event`: 
`userEvent.click(getByLabelText("Select Label")); userEvent.click(within(getByRole("listbox")).getByText("Option Text"));`

Comment: @Kentr Setting label and clicking on the Label won't work as the label is applied only on the parent div, clicking on it won't trigger the popup to open.

Comment: @AswinPrasad Here's a working example of using the label: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-mui-select-ogwjy?file=/demo.test.js). The test doesn't run on codesandbox, possibly due my error. The test _does_ run (and pass) on my computer.

Comment: I wish I saw this answer 3 hours ago... Thank you so much for the straight forward answer about the click event not being used for opening the list box.

Comment: @nnattawat Corrected link : https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/Select/Select.test.js

Comment: One thing that I don't like about this approach is that it is not a practical solution when you have multiple select field in a form, just looking by role='button' is very generic and doesn't differentiate it from other Select fields :(

Comment: you can use userEvent.click(yourselectcomponent) to open the dropdown/listbox if you use await in front of it:
`const input = screen.getByLabelText("Input Label")`

`await userEvent.click(input)`

`...the rest of your test`

(your test has to be async now, too, of course)

Answer (score 12):

#### Using `*ByLabelText()`

##### Component

```js
// demo.js
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [theThing, setTheThing] = React.useState("None");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setTheThing(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Choose a thing</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={theThing}
          label="Choose a thing"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={"None"}>None</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={"Meerkat"}>Meerkat</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={"Marshmallow"}>Marshmallow</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <Box sx={{ padding: 2 }}>
        <Typography>The thing is: {theThing}</Typography>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

##### Test

```js
// demo.test.js
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { render, screen, within } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import Demo from "./demo";

test("When I choose a thing, then the thing changes", async () => {
  render(<Demo />);

  // Confirm default state.
  expect(await screen.findByText(/the thing is: none/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

  // Click on the MUI "select" (as found by the label).
  const selectLabel = /choose a thing/i;
  const selectEl = await screen.findByLabelText(selectLabel);

  expect(selectEl).toBeInTheDocument();

  userEvent.click(selectEl);

  // Locate the corresponding popup (`listbox`) of options.
  const optionsPopupEl = await screen.findByRole("listbox", {
    name: selectLabel
  });

  // Click an option in the popup.
  userEvent.click(within(optionsPopupEl).getByText(/marshmallow/i));

  // Confirm the outcome.
  expect(
    await screen.findByText(/the thing is: marshmallow/i)
  ).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-mui-select-ogwjy?file=/demo.test.js) *Note:* Test doesn't run on codesandbox, but does run and pass on local.

Comment: It seems the key is using `within`.

Comment: `getByLabelText` is the only thing that worked for me. `data-testids` were not working.

Answer (score 10):

Using Material UI 5.10.3, this is how to simulate a click on the `Select` component, and to subsequently grab/verify the item values, and to click one of them to trigger the underlying change event:

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen, within } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MenuItem, Select } from '@mui/material';

describe('MUI Select Component', () => {
  it('should have correct options an handle change', () => {
    const spyOnSelectChange = jest.fn();

    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <div>
        <Select
          data-testid={'component-under-test'}
          value={''}
          onChange={(evt) => spyOnSelectChange(evt.target.value)}
        >
          <MenuItem value="menu-a">OptionA</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="menu-b">OptionB</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </div>
    );

    const selectCompoEl = getByTestId('component-under-test');

    const button = within(selectCompoEl).getByRole('button');
    fireEvent.mouseDown(button);

    const listbox = within(screen.getByRole('presentation')).getByRole(
      'listbox'
    );

    const options = within(listbox).getAllByRole('option');
    const optionValues = options.map((li) => li.getAttribute('data-value'));

    expect(optionValues).toEqual(['menu-a', 'menu-b']);

    fireEvent.click(options[1]);
    expect(spyOnSelectChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith('menu-b');
  });
});
```

Also posted [here](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/322#issuecomment-1236191573).

Comment: The only solution that worked for me. However, the DOM seems to be pretty scrambled at the end (options stay on 'screen').

Comment: If  you want to use `getByText`: `const selectCompoEl = (screen.getByText('OptionA') as HTMLElement).parentElement;`

Comment: How to do this if the select component is a separate component? @Gabriel?

Comment: What do you mean by a separate component?

Comment: It's the only one that worked for me as well. The trick is in the `.getByRole('button')` 

Answer (score 7):

Here is a working example for MUI TextField with Select option.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-chandrasekhar-vq2x0?file=/src/__tests__/TextSelect.test.tsx:0-1668

Textfield:

```
import { TextField, MenuItem, InputAdornment } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useState } from "react";

export const sampleData = [
  {
    name: "Vat-19",
    value: 1900
  },
  {
    name: "Vat-0",
    value: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Vat-7",
    value: 700
  }
];

export default function TextSelect() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(sampleData[0].name);

  return (
    <TextField
      id="vatSelectTextField"
      select
      label="#ExampleLabel"
      value={selected}
      onChange={(evt) => {
        setSelected(evt.target.value);
      }}
      variant="outlined"
      color="secondary"
      inputProps={{
        id: "vatSelectInput"
      }}
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">%</InputAdornment>
      }}
      fullWidth
    >
      {sampleData.map((vatOption) => (
        <MenuItem key={vatOption.name} value={vatOption.name}>
          {vatOption.name} - {vatOption.value / 100} %
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </TextField>
  );
}
```

Test:

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import TextSelect, { sampleData } from "../MuiTextSelect/TextSelect";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

describe("Tests TextField Select change", () => {

  test("Changes the selected value", () => {
    const { getAllByRole, getByRole, container } = render(<TextSelect />);

    //CHECK DIV CONTAINER
    let vatSelectTextField = container.querySelector(
      "#vatSelectTextField"
    ) as HTMLDivElement;
    expect(vatSelectTextField).toBeInTheDocument();

    //CHECK DIV CONTAINER
    let vatSelectInput = container.querySelector(
      "#vatSelectInput"
    ) as HTMLInputElement;
    expect(vatSelectInput).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(vatSelectInput.value).toEqual(sampleData[0].name);

    // OPEN
    fireEvent.mouseDown(vatSelectTextField);

    //CHECKO OPTIONS
    expect(getByRole("listbox")).not.toEqual(null);
    // screen.debug(getByRole("listbox"));

    //CHANGE
    act(() => {
      const options = getAllByRole("option");
      // screen.debug(getAllByRole("option"));
      fireEvent.mouseDown(options[1]);
      options[1].click();
    });

    //CHECK CHANGED
    vatSelectInput = container.querySelector(
      "#vatSelectInput"
    ) as HTMLInputElement;
    expect(vatSelectInput.value).toEqual(sampleData[1].name);
  });
});

/**
 * HAVE A LOOK AT
 *
 *
 * https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Select/Select.test.js
 * (ll. 117-121)
 *
 * https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TextField/TextField.test.js
 *
 *
 */
```

Answer (score 3):

ref: typescript

I have verified this works with multiple select fields; however, for this to work be sure to create your MenuItem options like this:

```
<MenuItem value={value} aria-label={name}>
    {name}
</MenuItem>
```

Helper to click on a MUI Select.

```
export const clickSelect = async (element: HTMLElement, value: string) => {
  const button = await within(element).findByRole('button');
  await act(async () => {
    fireEvent.mouseDown(button);
  });

  const option = await screen.findByRole('option', {
    name: new RegExp(value, 'i'),
  });

  await act(async () => {
    fireEvent.click(option);
  });
};
```

In your test code:

```
test('test', async () => {
    //...
    const selectElement = screen.getByTestId('my-select-test-id');

    await clickSelect(selectElement, 'Option Name');
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me while using MUI 5.

```
      userEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText(/^foo/i));
      userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('option', {name: /^bar/i}));
```

Comment: Didn't work. More context?

Comment: const element = screen.getByTestId("country");
await userEvent.click(within(element).getByRole("button"));
userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('option', {name: /^USA/i}));

Answer (score 1):

With MUI 5.10.5 it is enough if you set your data-testid using inputProps property

```
<Select ... inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'YOUR-TEST-ID-NAME' }} />
```

Later on you can fire event change on this element

```js
...
const selector = comp.getByTestId('YOUR-TEST-ID-NAME');

fireEvent.change(selector, { target: { value: 'Tested value' } });
```

Comment: The trick is to use `inputProps` instead of attaching `data-testid` directly to `Select`. Thanks to the trick, even the expect `toHaveValue` does work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as TestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { } from "mocha";

import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

let container;

beforeEach(() => {
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(container);
    container = null;
});

describe("Testing Select component", () => {

    test('start empty, open and select second option', (done) => {

        //render the component
        ReactDOM.render(<Select
            displayEmpty={true}
            value={""}
            onChange={(e) => {
                console.log(e.target.value);
            }}
            disableUnderline
            classes={{
                root: `my-select-component`
            }}
        >
            <MenuItem value={""}>All</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={"1"}>1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={"2"}>2</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={"3"}>3</MenuItem>
        </Select>, container);

        //open filter
        TestUtils.Simulate.click(container.querySelector('.my-select-component'));

        const secondOption = container.ownerDocument.activeElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll('li')[1];
        TestUtils.Simulate.click(secondOption);

        done();

    });
});
```

Comment: We may go down this route but am trying to avoid using TesUtils.Simulate as it is not a real event and so is not the truest test we could be doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
it('Set min zoom', async () => { 
  const minZoomSelect = await waitForElement( () => component.getByTestId('min-zoom') );
  fireEvent.click(minZoomSelect.childNodes[0]);

  const select14 = await waitForElement( () => component.getByText('14') );
  expect(select14).toBeInTheDocument();

  fireEvent.click(select14);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with Material UI select element but at the end I found this simple solution.

```
const handleSubmit = jest.fn()

const renderComponent = (args?: any) => {
  const defaultProps = {
    submitError: '',
    allCurrencies: [{ name: 'CAD' }, { name: 'EUR' }],
    setSubmitError: () => jest.fn(),
    handleSubmit,
    handleClose,
  }

  const props = { ...defaultProps, ...args }
  return render(<NewAccontForm {...props} />)
}

afterEach(cleanup)

// TEST

describe('New Account Form tests', () => {
  it('submits form with corret data', async () => {
    const expectedSubmitData = {
      account_type: 'Personal',
      currency_type: 'EUR',
      name: 'MyAccount',
    }
    const { getByRole, getAllByDisplayValue } = renderComponent()
    const inputs = getAllByDisplayValue('')
    fireEvent.change(inputs[0], { target: { value: 'Personal' } })
    fireEvent.change(inputs[1], { target: { value: 'EUR' } })
    fireEvent.change(inputs[2], { target: { value: 'MyAccount' } })
    userEvent.click(getByRole('button', { name: 'Confirm' }))
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedSubmitData)
      expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done with multiple Select in one page, try this one:

```
import { render, fireEvent, within } from '@testing-library/react'

 it('Should trigger select-xxx methiod', () => {
  const { getByTestId, getByRole: getByRoleParent } = component
  const element = getByTestId('select-xxx');
  const { getByRole } = within(element)
  const select = getByRole('button')
  fireEvent.mouseDown(select);
  const list = within(getByRoleParent('listbox')) // get list opened by trigger fireEvent
  fireEvent.click(list.getByText(/just try/i)); //select by text
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who have multiple Selects, make sure to add the `name` prop

```
          <SelectDropdown
            name="date_range"
            ...
          >
            ...
          </SelectDropdown>
          <SelectDropdown
            name="company"
            ...
          >
            ...
          </SelectDropdown>
```

```
    // date filter
    const date_range_dropdown = getByLabelText('Date Range');
    fireEvent.mouseDown(date_range_dropdown);
    await screen.findByRole('listbox');
    fireEvent.click(
      within(screen.getByRole('listbox')).getByText(/Last 30 Days/)
    );

    // // company filter
    const company_dropdown = getByLabelText('Company');
    fireEvent.mouseDown(company_dropdown);
    fireEvent.click(within(getByRole('listbox')).getByText(/Uber/));
```

Comment: `Unable to find role="listbox"`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I normally do it for MUI v5, make sure you follow [accessibility guideline for select component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#accessibility).

```js
render(<Component />)

const selectInput = screen.getByLabelText("your label")
expect(selectInput).toHaveTextContent("expected value")
```

The difference is instead of using `expect(input).toHaveValue` like normal `input` element, since the rendered `input` of MUI v5 Select is hidden and not linked to rendered `label`, we try to assert the `div` that was linked to the rendered `label` instead. Naming of variables could be better but hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i used the mouseDown event relative to the MUI Select component to be able to trigger the popup menu

```
  it('can see devices tree view', async () => {
    const onChangeHandler = jest.fn();
    const { getByRole } = render(
      <Select onChange={onChangeHandler} value="0">
        <MenuItem value="TEST1" />
        <MenuItem value="TEST2" />
        <MenuItem value="TEST3" />
      </Select>,
    );
    // menu items are not visible
    screen.debug(undefined, 100_000);
    fireEvent.mouseDown(getByRole('combobox'));
    // menu items are visible
    screen.debug(undefined, 100_000);
  });
```