# Unable to select option from mui select after opening the dropdown

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I open the dropdown using mousdown event on dropdown button.Then after zeroing down on the option I click and waitfor it to reflect but it is not getting selected

The below code is similar to mine and I followed this but even then it didn't work.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-material-ui-select-forked-h5fduy?file=/src/App.test.js

Comment: Can you provide a screen of the problem or can you share the code snippet of the problem?

Comment: Any luck with this yet?

Comment: I don't have the screen @wildgamer

Comment: No,I didn't get a solution for the case @ShwetaJ

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55184037/react-testing-library-on-change-for-material-ui-select-component