# Testing with Jest React Mui table pagination

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, datatable, material-ui

I have basic MUI data table with pagination https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/. I used it in NEXT page. When I want to test in Jest changing page rows number range from 5 to 10 clicking change range button don't show pop up menu.

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfgDk.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfgDk.png)]

Table footer render such html.

```
<div class="MuiTablePagination-root css-jtlhu6-MuiTablePagination-root" data-testid="tablePagination" style="display: block;">
 <div class="MuiToolbar-root MuiToolbar-gutters MuiToolbar-regular MuiTablePagination-toolbar css-78c6dr-MuiToolbar-root-MuiTablePagination-toolbar">
  <div class="MuiTablePagination-spacer css-1psng7p-MuiTablePagination-spacer"></div>
  <p class="MuiTablePagination-selectLabel css-pdct74-MuiTablePagination-selectLabel" id=":r7:">Rows per page:</p>
  <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInputBase-colorPrimary Mui-focused css-16c50h-MuiInputBase-root-MuiTablePagination-select">
   <div tabindex="0" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-labelledby=":r7: :r6:" id=":r6:" class="MuiSelect-select MuiTablePagination-select MuiSelect-standard MuiInputBase-input css-194a1fa-MuiSelect-select-MuiInputBase-input">5</div>
   <input aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" class="MuiSelect-nativeInput css-yf8vq0-MuiSelect-nativeInput" value="5"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium MuiSelect-icon MuiTablePagination-selectIcon MuiSelect-iconStandard MuiSelect-iconOpen css-1mf6u8l-MuiSvgIcon-root-MuiSelect-icon" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-testid="ArrowDropDownIcon">
   <path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path></svg></div><p class="MuiTablePagination-displayedRows css-levciy-MuiTablePagination-displayedRows">1–5 of 6</p><div class="MuiTablePagination-actions"> 
    <button class="MuiButtonBase-root Mui-disabled MuiIconButton-root Mui-disabled MuiIconButton-colorInherit MuiIconButton-sizeMedium css-zylse7-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root" tabindex="-1" type="button" disabled="" aria-label="Go to previous page" title="Go to previous page">
     <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium css-i4bv87-MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-testid="KeyboardArrowLeftIcon"><path d="M15.41 16.09l-4.58-4.59 4.58-4.59L14 5.5l-6 6 6 6z"></path></svg>
   </button>
   <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiIconButton-colorInherit MuiIconButton-sizeMedium css-zylse7-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="Go to next page" title="Go to next page">
    <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium css-i4bv87-MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-testid="KeyboardArrowRightIcon"><path d="M8.59 16.34l4.58-4.59-4.58-4.59L10 5.75l6 6-6 6z"></path></svg>
    <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-8je8zh-MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
   </button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

There is div with role button and tabindex=0 as well as input with tabindex=1. I can find those elements and fireEvent.click on them but it don't generate in dom menu on which I can choose row numbers.

```
<div role="presentation" class="MuiPopover-root MuiMenu-root MuiModal-root css-10nakn3-MuiModal-root-MuiPopover-root-MuiMenu-root" id="menu-">
 <div aria-hidden="true" class="MuiBackdrop-root MuiBackdrop-invisible css-g3hgs1-MuiBackdrop-root-MuiModal-backdrop" style="opacity: 1; transition: opacity 225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;"></div> 
 <div tabindex="0" data-testid="sentinelStart"></div>
 <div class="MuiPaper-root MuiPaper-elevation MuiPaper-rounded MuiPaper-elevation1 MuiPaper-root MuiMenu-paper MuiPaper-elevation MuiPaper-rounded MuiPaper-elevation8 MuiPopover-paper css-1poimk-MuiPaper-root-MuiMenu-paper-MuiPaper-root-MuiPopover-paper" tabindex="-1" style="opacity: 1; transform: none; min-width: 48px; transition: opacity 242ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms, transform 161ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms; top: 600px; left: 452px; transform-origin: 24px 53.6625px;">
  <ul class="MuiList-root MuiList-padding MuiMenu-list css-6hp17o-MuiList-root-MuiMenu-list" role="listbox" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby=":r7:">
   <li class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters Mui-selected MuiTablePagination-menuItem css-10by3a5-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiMenuItem-root-MuiTablePagination-menuItem" tabindex="0" role="option" aria-selected="true" data-value="5">5<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-8je8zh-MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></li>
   <li class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiTablePagination-menuItem css-10by3a5-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiMenuItem-root-MuiTablePagination-menuItem" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-value="10">10<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-8je8zh-MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></li>
   <li class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiTablePagination-menuItem css-10by3a5-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiMenuItem-root-MuiTablePagination-menuItem" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-value="25">25<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-8je8zh-MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
<div tabindex="0" data-testid="sentinelEnd"></div>
</div>
```

I see in chrome dev tools that parent div of this element have click event listener but event if I fireEvent click on this div menu don't show. Also I see that when I click as I think button element in browser

```
<div tabindex="0" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-labelledby=":r7: :r6:" id=":r6:" class="MuiSelect-select MuiTablePagination-select MuiSelect-standard MuiInputBase-input css-194a1fa-MuiSelect-select-MuiInputBase-input">5</div>
```

aria-expanded is changing from false to true but when I do it in jest it stays false. In browser I see that this menu is added as last child of body element dynamically after I click change rows number. The problem is that mui table don't use there regualr select but firing addidiotnal pop over menu after click button.

EDIT
Correct answer how to deal with mui select is here (this most voted with fireEvent.mouseDown) [React testing library on change for Material UI Select component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55184037/react-testing-library-on-change-for-material-ui-select-component)

Comment: I have the same issue.  I've tried fireEvent clicking the 'svg' (data-testid="arrowDropDownIcon", but that doesn't create the ul/li dom elements.  I also tried changing 'input' value, but none of these trigger the 'onRowsPerPageChange' function, which is what I need in my unit tests.  fireEvent clicking the previous and next row svg's does work and triggers the 'onPageChange' event.  So I don't know why it doesn't work for the rows per page list.

Comment: I have the same problem, could you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but for anyone struggling with this, the problem is actually the "fireEvent.click". The combobox element only worked with "fireEvent.mouseDown".

Here's my code:

```
const paginationSelect = getByRole('combobox');
fireEvent.mouseDown(paginationSelect);
```

Answer (score 0):

*I Also Face the same issue and following is my solution for the same.*

We can open the select page size options by triggering the button selectPageOptions.
After that page size options element can be selected using the "options" role.

```
const selectPageOptions = getByRole("button", {
  name: /5/,
});
await act(() => userEvent.click(selectPageOptions));
const select10Page = getByRole("option", { name: /10/ });
await act(() => userEvent.click(select10Page));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the code bellow

```
fireEvent.mouseDown(
  screen.getByRole("button", {
    name: /rows per page: 10/i
  })
};
fireEvent.click(
  screen.getByRole("option", {
    name: /25/i
  })
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```js
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

await userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: /5/ }));
```

Comment: TablePagination element does not create clickable buttons but is supposed to create UL/UI elements.  Since these UL/UI elements are not being created after clicking the SVG element then there is nothing to click to change the rows per page.